# _mm_load_si128 - Passed memory address is not 16-byte-aligned?

Tags: c++, simd, sse2

I've got some trouble understanding a SSE2-instruction. According to the microsoft documentation, [_mm_load_si128](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atzzad1h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) requires a 16-byte-aligned address as parameter. In the code, which I try to understand, this seems not to be the case:

```
void f(uchar* buf0, const int n)
{
    ushort* buf = (ushort*)alignPtr(buf0, 16);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i += 16)
    {
        __m128i v0 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(buf+i));   // 16-byte-aligned, since buf is 16-byte-aligned and i is divisable by 16.
        __m128i v1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(buf+i+8)); // If buf+i is 16-byte-aligned, then buf+i+8 cannot be 16-byte-aligned.
    }
}
```

I reduced the code to the relevant part and renamed some variables. The original code is from the OpenCV implementation of Konoliges blockmatching algorithm (stereobm.cpp, especially line 313). My question is, why is the code correct and what is written into v1?

Comment: Actually, it *would* be 16-aligned (apparently - otherwise you'd get an exception); you're adding 8 but it gets multiplied by the size of `ushort`

Comment: Address arithmetic is in action here. `buf+i+8` means that address of `buf` is incremented by `sizeof(ushort)*(i+8)`, which equals to `2*(i+8)`. So, `2*8` have no influence to alignment.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I did not realize (or forgot), that operator+ was implemented this way for pointers. Now the code makes sense.